# how to remove lines on the photo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I got a work from a customer to print a big size photo(12inx15in) from a passport size photo(3.5cmx4.5cm). When i enlarge it lines are seen on the photo.

i tried to use the S tool to remove the lines, but no use. Any other possobilities to remove the lines on the face?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enlarging the image by at least 2x, then apply a motion blur perpendicular to the direction of the lines. You can then reduce the image back to the starting size, and apply an unsharp mask.

Answer (score 0):

Just blur the image until the lines disappear. I just did a quick test and you won’t lose much detail.

You might want to colour correct the image a little too though. There is a lot of blue in the skin tone.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is. The image has lot of blue. I've posted the image without color correction.